# airasia tranfer to airasia x luggauge

Tags: luggage

airasia transfer to airasia x luggage do I need to check out at the transfer airport and checkin luggage again ? or Is it same airline and auto transfer luggage to next air plane

Comment: Are you flying domestic or international? What city are you transferring in? Please update with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Air Asia and Air Asia X are point to point airlines, you and your baggage are checked for each individual leg at each airport.  And your fee for bags is also per leg.

They do offer a program called FlyThru, with which your bags are checked through to the final destination.  But it is available only at a couple of their hubs and applies to certain city pairs.